# Getting count with conditions in sub query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have 4 tables, below. I need to get a count of the `contact_made_id` from the `contact_made` table for records where the 'status_loan_id' = 33 or 43

I could do this with a sub query however I need to both get the count in the query result and **order by the count** in the joined query

1. loans

```
    loan_id | Client_id
    ---------------------
    9727    |   12668
    9780    |   12720
    9781    |   12721
    9782    |   12722
    9783    |   12723
    9784    |   12724
    9785    |   12725
```

2. clients

```
    Client_id
    ---------------------
    12668
    12720
    12721
    12722
    12723
    12724
    12725
```

3. clients_coms

```
    client_coms_id |   client_id
    -----------------------------
    2114           |   12668 
    2115           |   12668 
    2116           |   12668 
    2117           |   12668  
    2121           |   12668 
    2122           |   12668  
    2260           |   12720 
    2261           |   12720  
    2262           |   12720  
    2263           |   12721  
    2264           |   12721  
    2265           |   12721  
    2266           |   12722  
    2267           |   12722  
    2268           |   12723 
    2269           |   12723  
    2270           |   12723  
    2271           |   12723  
    2272           |   12724  
    2273           |   12724 
    2274           |   12724  
    2275           |   12724 
    2276           |   12725 
    2277           |   12725  
    2278           |   12725
```

4. contact_made

```
    contact_made_id | loan_id | status_loan_id
    1               | 9727    | 3  
    2               | 9727    | 3  
    3               | 9727    | 34   
    4               | 9727    | 33  
    5               | 9727    | 3 
    6               | 9727    | 33 
    9               | 9727    | 3 
    0               | 9727    | 3 
    11              | 9782    | 33 
    12              | 9782    | 3 
    13              | 9782    | 33 
    14              | 9782    | 3 
    15              | 9782    | 34
```

I have the below SQL however it gives the following incorrect output

```
SELECT 
l.loan_id, 
COUNT(cm.contact_made_id) AS contact_count
FROM loans l
LEFT JOIN contact_made cm 
          ON l.loan_id = cm.loan_id 
          AND (cm.status_loan_id = 33 OR cm.status_loan_id = 34)
LEFT JOIN clients_coms com 
          ON l.client_id = com.client_id
GROUP BY l.loan_id
ORDER BY contact_count ASC
```

Outputs...

```
loan_id | contact_count     
------------------------
9780    | 0
9781    | 0
9783    | 0
9784    | 0
9785    | 0
9782    | 6
9727    | 18
```

Should output...

```
loan_id | contact_count     
------------------------
9780    | 0
9781    | 0
9783    | 0
9784    | 0
9785    | 0
9782    | 2
9727    | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

To avoid duplicates, you could simply use the `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`, like :

```
COUNT(DISTINCT cm.contact_made_id) AS contact_count
```

But as far as concerned, you do not need to `JOIN clients_coms`, as the `loan_id` is available in both `contact_made` and `loans` tables. Removing this join avoids duplicates, and hence the need to use `DISTINCT`. I also changed you `OR` conditions on `loan_id` to an `IN` condition.

```
SELECT l.loan_id, COUNT(cm.loan_id) contact_count
FROM 
    loans l 
    LEFT JOIN contact_made cm 
        ON l.loan_id = cm.loan_id 
        AND cm.status_loan_id IN (33, 34)
GROUP BY loan_id
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

Yields :

```
| loan_id | contact_count |
| ------- | ------------- |
| 9780    | 0             |
| 9781    | 0             |
| 9783    | 0             |
| 9784    | 0             |
| 9785    | 0             |
| 9727    | 3             |
| 9782    | 3             |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kiUcQRPxGZKUaemux8fqbx/0)**.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what it needed. By the way, the cleints_coms was joined for another reason, and I thought Id keep it in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you run it with where condition?

```
SELECT 
l.loan_id, 
COUNT(cm.contact_made_id) AS contact_count
FROM loans l
LEFT JOIN contact_made cm 
          ON l.loan_id = cm.loan_id 
LEFT JOIN clients_coms com 
          ON l.client_id = com.client_id
WHERE cm.status_loan_id in (33, 34)
GROUP BY l.loan_id
ORDER BY contact_count ASC
```

if not, try with Inner Join+Where condition

Comment: Adding it in WHERE outputs only the rows which have that condition. I need all loan_id's